# authentification with jsf and postgresql

Tags: postgresql, jsf

i try to do authentification with jsf and postgres database.
my class conect.java

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean 
@SessionScoped
public class connect {
private  boolean connected;
 private  String pass;
  private   String user;
      private   String message;

public boolean isConnected() {
    return connected;
}

public void setConnected(boolean connected) {
    this.connected = connected;
}

public String getPass() {
    return pass;
}

public void setPass(String pass) {
    this.pass = pass;
}

public String getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(String user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
  }

  public void setMessage(String message) {
      this.message = message;
  }


 public String check()
 {
   Connection c = null;
   Statement stmt = null;
   try {

     c = DriverManager
        .getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/login", "postgres", "1234");
     c.setAutoCommit(false);
     System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

     stmt = c.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM users;" );
     while ( rs.next() ) {

       int iduser = rs.getInt("iduser");
         String  username = rs.getString("username");
        String password  = rs.getString("password");
         System.out.println( "ID = " + iduser );
      System.out.println( "USERNAME = " + username );
      System.out.println( "PASSWORD = " + password );



  if(user.equals(username) &&(pass.equals(password))){

   message="admin";
  }
 else message="error";

     }
     rs.close();
     stmt.close();
     c.close();
   } catch ( Exception e ) {
     System.err.println( e.getClass().getName()+": "+ e.getMessage() );

   }
   System.out.println("Operation done successfully");
   return message;
 }


public connect() {
}

public static void main( String args[] ){
connect c= new connect();
c.check();
}
```

}

The program recovers well information from the database, the problem is that this program takes into account just the latest username and password of the "users" table. Can someone tell me where is the problem

Comment: You appear to not grasp some SQL and JDBC fundamentals such as PreparedStatements and the WHERE clause. Not to mention the fact that your `check` method is basically opening a new database connection for every login request.

Comment: Can you give me more explanation or an example because iam new in java